# Angular : Retrieve Name property using find not working

Tags: json, angular

I have the following service call in angular that returns an object FundStrategies which has the following json format. I basically need to extract the name based on the matching id field. When I do a console.log on this.SelectedFundStrategy , I get undefined. Could somebody tell me what the problem is ? It is printing the value of this.ManagerStrategyId via console.log correctly

```
this.SelectedFundStrategy = data.FundStrategies.find(x => x.Id === this.ManagerStrategyId);
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "Id": 243100,
    "Name": "2020 Bulkers - Titan",
    "SortOrder": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 7209,
    "Name": "A.R.T. International Strategy",
    "SortOrder": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 241951,
    "Name": "Adient - Blue Harbour",
    "SortOrder": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 300026,
    "Name": "Distressed - GoldenTree",
    "SortOrder": null
  }
]
```

Component

```
@Input() ManagerStrategyId: number;
SelectedFundStrategy: any;

public getFundDetails(selectedFundId: number, refresh: boolean = true) {
        if(refresh) 
            this.FundDetails = null;

        this.Loading = true;
        this.EditMode = false;
        this.IsInsertMode = false;

        if (!selectedFundId) {
            selectedFundId = -1;
        }
            this.fundService.getFundDetails(selectedFundId).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.FundDetails = data;
                this.FundStrategies = data.FundStrategies;
                this.SelectedFundStrategy = data.FundStrategies.find(x => x.Id === this.ManagerStrategyId);
                console.log(this.SelectedFundStrategy);


                this.SelectedFundId = this.FundDetails.FundId;
                this.vehicleTypeChanged(this.FundDetails.VehicleTypeId);
                this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
                this.Loading = false;

                if(this.FundDetails.FundId === 0){
                    this.EditMode = true;
                    this.IsInsertMode = true;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: check the  type of this.ManagerStrategyId

Comment: I have updated the types in the post

Comment: ManagerStrategyId can be string at runtime. Try `x.Id == this.ManagerStrategyId`